# kvm.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disable on this system

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to run the `Asp.net vNext` sample application.

But when i try to execute the command

```
kvm list
```

It gives me the error message

```
kvm.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disable on this system
```

I tried to change to execution policy also. But still i am getting the same error.

Comment: Are you in powershell or command prompt?

Comment: I am trying to execute the command in powershell

Comment: Try the command prompt may be and see what happens.

Comment: yes it works in command prompt. Thanks @sunil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

execute this command on console

```
**"powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned"**,
```

after that run the commands bellow

```
$tempPath = Join-Path $env:TEMP "kvminstall"
$kvmPs1Path = Join-Path $tempPath "kvm.ps1"
$kvmCmdPath = Join-Path $tempPath "kvm.cmd"

Write-Host "Using temporary directory: $tempPath"
if (!(Test-Path $tempPath)) { md $tempPath | Out-Null }


$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
Write-Host "Downloading KVM.ps1 to $kvmPs1Path"
$webClient.DownloadFile('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/master/kvm.ps1', $kvmPs1Path)
Write-Host "Downloading KVM.cmd to $kvmCmdPath"
$webClient.DownloadFile('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/master/kvm.cmd', $kvmCmdPath)
Write-Host "Installing KVM"
& $kvmCmdPath setup
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the powershell command `Unblock-File`?